# Simulating Typing Activity - Bot Framework Composer

Tags: asp.net-core, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm trying to add typing to my bot using Composer, but I have no clue how to access the Typing activity.

```
[Activity
    type = Typing
]
```

I have also tried the chatdown markup language, but I seem to be formating that wrong as well.

```
[Typing][Delay=3000]
```

Neither of the .lg formats above simulate typing.

[image]

Comment: You can try following the given sample it would work accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the typing activity is working in Bot Framework Composer, you can also see it in action here: https://youtu.be/wG8emu4v6hk?t=955 (brief moment at 15:55). The sample source can be found here: https://github.com/vishwacsena/composer-build-2020/tree/master/Birthday-bot2

[image]

The activity is sent the exact way you describe, but it is only shown until the next response has been sent. In the example screenshot, the delay is caused by the HTTP request, and during this time the typing activity is shown. If your responses are following each other quickly, you might not see the typing indicator at all as the process goes too quickly.

```
[Activity
    type = Typing
]
```

I was able to simulate the above as well in my own Bot Framework Composer project, where I used a custom action to simulate a short delay. During the delay the Typing activity is shown.

Comment: Yes, my question was before Composer GA got announced. The version I got from GitHub did not currently have the typing middleware.

It is now fixed and supported in GA.

Comment: @bartbillet Is it possible to send the activitie also before QnA Maker? Tried to response with the typing before the "Connect to QnA" Task ... nothing happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`Typing indicator` on bot composer should be implement following way:

To make it working you have to follow below steps:

***Enable Typing Middleware on Bot Composer:***

Important thing is you should enable the `typing middleware` to `true`
like this `"showTyping": true,`

You can do this way:

***`Step: 1`***

[image]
***`Step:2`***

```
 "features": {
      "removeRecipientMentions": false,
      "showTyping": true,
      "traceTranscript": false,
      "useInspection": false,
      "setSpeak": {
        "voiceFontName": "en-US-JennyNeural",
        "fallbackToTextForSpeechIfEmpty": true
      }
    }
```

[image]

Add Your Typing Activity on SendResponse

```
[Activity
    Type = Typing
]
```

[image]

> ***Note:*** Paste code by Clicking on show code like below:

Then Paste your Typing activity code below:

[image]
[image]

Add Delay Time so that it can get time to display:

```
[Activity
    Value = ${3000}
    Type = ${"delay"}
]
```

[image]

> ***Note:*** Same as above process. First show the code then paste delay activity. Means click on show code then paste the `delay activity` there

***Final Out put:***

final output should be like below:

[image]

> **Note:** For ***`Bot Fremework SDK`*** you can implement this way:

```cs
 //take some delay and reply card
 await turnContext.SendActivitiesAsync(new Activity[] { new Activity { Type = ActivityTypes.Typing }, new Activity { Type = "delay", Value = 3000 } });
```

Hope above steps guided to implement `typing indicator` on bot conversation both on `SDK` and `Composer`